# How do I produce reproducible randomness with OpenAi-Gym and Scoop?

Tags: random, concurrency, python-3.8, openai-gym, python-scoop

How do I produce reproducible randomness with OpenAi-Gym and Scoop?

I want to have the exact same results every time I repeat the example. If possible I want this to work with existing libraries which use randomness-provider (e.g. random and np.random), which can be a problem because they usually use the global random-state and don't provide an interface for a local random state

My example script looks like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from scoop import futures
import gym


def do(it):
    random.seed(it)
    np.random.seed(it)
    env.seed(it)
    env.action_space.seed(it)
    env.reset()
    observations = []
    for i in range(3):
        while True:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            ob, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            observations.append(ob)
            if done:
                break
    return observations


env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v3")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    maxit = 20
    results1 = futures.map(do, range(2, maxit))
    results2 = futures.map(do, range(2, maxit))
    for a,b in zip(results1, results2):
        if np.array_equiv(a, b):
            print("equal, yay")
        else:
            print("not equal :(")
```

expected output: `equal, yay` on every line

actual output: `not equal :(` on multipe lines

full output:

```
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/bin/python -m scoop /home/chef/dev/projekte/NeuroEvolution-CTRNN_new/random_test.py
[2020-05-18 18:05:03,578] launcher  INFO    SCOOP 0.7 1.1 on linux using Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) [GCC 9.3.0], API: 1013
[2020-05-18 18:05:03,578] launcher  INFO    Deploying 4 worker(s) over 1 host(s).
[2020-05-18 18:05:03,578] launcher  INFO    Worker distribution: 
[2020-05-18 18:05:03,578] launcher  INFO       127.0.0.1:   3 + origin
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
equal, yay
not equal :(
not equal :(
not equal :(
not equal :(
not equal :(
equal, yay
not equal :(
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
not equal :(
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
not equal :(
[2020-05-18 18:05:08,554] launcher  (127.0.0.1:37729) INFO    Root process is done.
[2020-05-18 18:05:08,554] launcher  (127.0.0.1:37729) INFO    Finished cleaning spawned subprocesses.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I run this example without scoop, I get almost perfect results:

```
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/bin/python /home/chef/dev/projekte/NeuroEvolution-CTRNN_new/random_test.py
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
/home/chef/.venv/neuro/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scoop/fallbacks.py:38: RuntimeWarning: SCOOP was not started properly.
Be sure to start your program with the '-m scoop' parameter. You can find further information in the documentation.
Your map call has been replaced by the builtin serial Python map().
  warnings.warn(
not equal :(
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay
equal, yay

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could "solve" it by moving the creation of the gym into the do-function.

The full corrected code would look like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from scoop import futures
import gym


def do(it):
    env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v3")
    random.seed(it)
    np.random.seed(it)
    env.seed(it)
    env.action_space.seed(it)
    env.reset()
    observations = []
    for i in range(3):
        while True:
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            ob, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            observations.append(ob)
            if done:
                break
    return observations


if __name__ == "__main__":
    maxit = 20
    results1 = futures.map(do, range(2, maxit))
    results2 = futures.map(do, range(2, maxit))
    for a,b in zip(results1, results2):
        if np.array_equiv(a, b):
            print("equal, yay")
        else:
            print("not equal :(")
```